# Android deeplink via chrome intent broke since april 2022

Tags: android, deep-linking

Currently, in our organization we use chrome intent to deeplink app if app is present else it is routed to msite but since aprl 2022 it broke for all apps and most of them are routed to msite.

Below is the implementation snippet

in mailer/sms we send URL

https://www.deeplink.xyz.com/fgh

on click of the above link, it takes users to browser

at backend we check some case and trigger chrome intent as below

xzyapp://dl?HTTP://www.someurl.com/dl?type=xyz

In-App we have added deeplink handling code as below

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="dl"
                android:scheme="xzyapp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Any help would be appriciated